# Looking for a movie in which a cheating husband was assaulted in a hotel with the other woman

Tags: identify-this-movie

There was a movie in which a married man knew an attractive woman in a train (I guess), and they went to an discrete hotel to occasionally have sex. They kept doing this till, one night, a criminal entered the room with a weapon.

I can't remind all the details, but... The guy rapes the woman and asks for money, then he blackmails the married man, or something like this. So he tries to get help from a policeman to deliver the money, but the criminal kills the policeman, and keeps blackmailing him, arguing that he didn't really give the money, as he had to kill to get it.

I'd guess it's a '90's movie, but it might be newer than this, not sure. I can't remember the movie's name, and would like some help.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like the exact plot of [Derailed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derailed_(2005_film)) from 2005 with Clive Owen and Jennifer Aniston.

> On a commuter train, Charles [Owen] encounters an alluring woman named Lucinda Harris [Aniston]. She is a married financial adviser. [...] Ultimately, they decide to consummate their affair and wind up in a seedy hotel. An armed man — later identified as Philippe LaRoche (Vincent Cassel) - bursts into the hotel room, beats Charles, and brutally rapes Lucinda. Charles and Lucinda agree not to report the crime, as they do not want their spouses to learn of the affair. Shortly after, Charles is blackmailed by LaRoche, who threatens to kill his family if he does not pay $20,000, which Charles promptly pays. A month later, the attacker calls again, this time demanding $100,000.

It turns out to be a scam that 'Lucinda' (real name Jane) is in on. Here's the trailer: